# Parsing a text file with bad json - PHP

Tags: php, parsing

I was given a badly formatted json file and I have to parse it using PHP.

```
{timestamp":"2022-03-25 00:25:41.476+00","order_id":"1659616"}{timestamp":"2022-03-25 00:18:51.892+00","order_id":"1560808"}{timestamp":"2022-03-25 00:23:52.267+00","order_id":"1727305"}
```

I want to use:

```
foreach(file("abovefile.txt") as $line) {
    
}
```

The issue is I don't have a new line.  How do I read in between the brackets and then extract timestamp and order_id for all entries?

What is the best way to do so?

Comment: How did the file end up like that? Can you not request a fixed version?

Comment: Alternatively, I'd be quite tempted to just turn it into valid JSON - it looks like the problems are: 1) missing " before timestamp each time, 2) missing commas between closing and opening brackets, 3) you'd need square brackets around the whole thing to make it an array. Those could all be sorted in a few moments in Notepad++ or any similar editor. Or if you need to process many such files a simple PHP script could clearn the data, and then you could json_decode it normally. Far easier than attempting to write your own parser for a wonky format.

Answer (score 1):

If this is the format and it's exactly like that, you can solve this with this "procedure":

```
$var = ''
foreach(file("abovefile.txt") as $line) {
    $var.= $line;
}
$var = '['.$var.']';
$var = str_replace('timestamp"', '"timestamp"', $var);
$var = str_replace('}{', '}, {', $var);
```